# I have django app and also have a function for arrange data of excel file i create in this want to pick file path from url

Tags: python, django, excel, file

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:        
            excel_file = request.FILES.get('file')
            file_data = excel_file.cleaned_data['file'].read()
            file_name = excel_file.cleaned_data['file'].name
            file = default_storage.save(file_name, ContentFile(file_data))
            xlxs = process_file(file, process_type='json', db_type='default')
            if xlxs:
                return HttpResponse(f'File path: {xlxs}')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("There was an error during the process.")
        except Exception as e:
                # Print the exception for debugging
                print(f"Error in process_file: {e}")
                return HttpResponse("An unexpected error occurred during the process.")
```

I want to resolve this from a library.

Comment: Select your code and Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0):

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            excel_file = request.FILES['file']
            file_data = excel_file.read()
            file_name = excel_file.name
            file_path = default_storage.save(file_name, ContentFile(file_data))
            xlxs = process_file(file_path, process_type='json', db_type='default') 
            if xlxs:
                return HttpResponse(f'Success! File path: {xlxs}')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("There was an error during the process.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in upload_file: {e}")
            return HttpResponse("An unexpected error occurred during the process.")
```